# Client is not authenticated

Tags: asp.net, email, iis

After I published my application and deployed it to IIS, I encountered this kind of error that says Client is not authenticated.

In my web.config, I have this line of code to set up smtp mail server.

```
 <system.net>
<mailSettings>
  <smtp>
    <network host="ap.smtp.lear.com" port="25" />
  </smtp>
</mailSettings>
```

And in my controller:

```
  public void Send(string[] to = null, string[] cc = null, string body = null)
    {
        MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
        message.From = new MailAddress("myapp@samp.com");

        //for to emails, since it is in array form, it will called individually by using foreach loop

        foreach (var em in to) {
            message.To.Add(new MailAddress(em));
        }

        foreach (var ccem in cc)
        {
            message.CC.Add(new MailAddress(ccem));
        }

        message.Subject = "Employee Regularization - For Approval";
        message.IsBodyHtml = true;
        message.Body = body;
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
        client.Send(message);
        message.Dispose();
        client.Dispose();
    }
```

I am deploying my application in the server that has also other applications hosted that can send emails. Is there something wrong or did I missed something?

Answer (score 0):

You said:

```
client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential();
```

But you didn't provide a username and password. Perhaps you should change [the overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.mailmessage%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) you use.

```
client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password");
```

Also, when you use `IDisposable` stuff, you need to make sure that the object gets disposed *even if there's an error*. Simply calling `.Dispose()` later in the code isn't good enough. If some error happens between when you declared the object and when you dispose it, then the `.Dispose()` won't be reached. There's two ways to do it. You can do a try/catch/finally and call `.Dispose()` in the finally block. Or you can use `using` statements. I've chosen the latter.

```
public void Send(string[] to = null, string[] cc = null, string body = null)
{
    using (MailMessage message = new MailMessage())
    {
        message.From = new MailAddress("myapp@samp.com");

        foreach (var em in to)
        {
            message.To.Add(new MailAddress(em));
        }

        foreach (var ccem in cc)
        {
            message.CC.Add(new MailAddress(ccem));
        }

        message.Subject = "Employee Regularization - For Approval";
        message.IsBodyHtml = true;
        message.Body = body;
        using(SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient())
        {
            client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password");
            client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            client.Send(message);
        }
    }
}
```